# When doing multiple updates with batch, the page is getting stuck in a loop

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update multiple documents using batch() and commit().
The intended document are getting updated but the page goes still and I cannot click or go back or refresh the page.

However, when I console log the output message its going on a loop recursively.

```
let users_DB = db.collection( `users/${ profileEmail }/details` )
    let currentDate = new Date()

    users_DB.onSnapshot( ( querySnapshot ) =>
    {
      var batch = firebase.firestore().batch()
      querySnapshot.forEach( ( doc ) =>
      {
        let dbDate = new Date( doc.data().dateInMills * 1000 )
        if ( dbDate >= currentDate )
        {
          batch.update( users_DB.doc( doc.id ), {
            'fees': parseInt( fees.value ),
            'timeStamp': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion( firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate( new Date() ) ),
          } )
        }
        batch.commit().then(() => {console.log( 'changes made.' );})

      } )
    } )
```

How do I ensure avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the [`CollectionReference#onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) method, you are listening for any changes to the data that matches the query. When you invoke `batch.commit()`, in addition to writing the new data to the server, all listeners will be notified that their data has changed - including your listener that's doing the update. Because you add a new element to the `timeStamp` field on every iteration, your code recursively calls itself.

To correct this, switch to a one time data retrieval using [`CollectionReference#get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) instead.

```js
const users_DB = db.collection(`users/${profileEmail}/details`);
const currentDate = new Date();

users_DB
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const batch = db.batch(); // use db instead of firebase.firestore() for consistency
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const dbDate = new Date(doc.get("dateInMills") * 1000); // dateInMills isn't in milliseconds?
      if (dbDate >= currentDate) {
        batch.update(doc.ref, {
          'fees': parseInt( fees.value ),
          'timeStamp': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())),
        });
      }
    }
    return batch.commit(); // this is a no-op if no changes are needed
  })
  .then(() => console.log("changes made"));
```

However, you can refine this with a query (which is how I would approach it):

```js
const nowMS = Date.now(),
  newData = {
    fees: parseInt(fees.value),
    timeStamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(nowMS))
  };

db.collection(`users/${profileEmail}/details`)
  .where("dateInMills", ">=", nowMS / 1000)
  .get()
  .then(qs => {
    const batch = db.batch();
    qs.forEach(docSnap => {
      batch.update(docSnap.ref, newData);
    });
    return batch.commit();
  })
  .then(() => console.log("changes made"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked exactly as intended. However, I was trying the second approach you showed but somehow it's not reflecting the changes in the Db though it logs 'changes made' in the browser. No error in the console either.

Comment: @alittlehotcurry hmm. I will admit that I wrote the second part without testing it. Probable causes are that the query returns no results (I don't log a different message - e.g. `if (qs.empty) { console.log("empty") }`), the `update()` call needs its own copy of the object rather than a shared one (either copy down the `newData` object inline or try `update(docSnap.ref, {...newData})`, you can it swap out for `set(docSnap.ref, newData, { merge: true })` (trying the variants of `newData` too), or maybe `arrayUnion` is picky about being reused.

Comment: Instead of using 'where' query in the Db path I filtered the fetch data and it worked. Could be because dataInMills is stored as an array in the Db and the 'where' query is not working when used in the Db path. 
I was under the impression firebase would pick the last element if the stored data is in an array when used with queries.

Comment: @alittlehotcurry Each array would be internally stored as `"someArr.0"`, `"someArr.1"`, `"someArr.2"`, and so on